# Rails routing - equal sign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my rails routing I have resource looks. And instead of /looks/:id Iwant to use /looks?look=:id. But if i write something like this:
map.look_one '/looks?look=:id', :controller => 'looks', :action => 'index'
I have an error.
This line works:
map.look_one '/looks?look#:id', :controller => 'looks', :action => 'index'

Answer (score 0):

This is actually much simpler than you're making it.

No matter what, you can always add parameters to a url after a `?`

Just try;

```
map.look_one '/looks', :controller => 'looks', :action => 'index'
```

This will create the path `/looks`, but equally you can link to `/looks?look=12345`

The latter will arrive at your controller with the `param[:look] == '12345'`.

Comment: Thanks, but I know that )
It's for link_to @look.title, look_one_path(@look)

Comment: Well the rails router is going to do that for you. It is all about paths.